# How to use a mixin when declaring a class

Tags: scala

Say I use a mixin as follows:

```
trait A {
    def foo: String
}

class B extends A {
    def foo = "B"
}

class C extends A {
    def foo = "C"
}

trait MixIn extends A {
    abstract override def foo = super.foo + " with MixIn"
}

val c = new C with MixIn
```

I have a scenario where I want to use the mixin when declaring a class rather than and instance. But when I try the following I get a compile error:

```
class D extends A with MixIn {
    def foo = "D"
}
```

> method foo needs `override' modifier

What is the appropriate way to use the mixin in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there

```
trait A {
  def foo: String
}
trait MixIn extends A {
  abstract override def foo = super.foo + " with MixIn"
}
abstract class beforeD extends A {
  override def foo = "D"
}
class D extends beforeD with MixIn
```

you just need concrete abstract implementation of foo which will be called as `super.foo` from MixIn

**Updated to case with animals**

```
abstract class LikeDog extends Animal {
  override def whoAmI: String = "I'm a dog"
}

class Dog extends LikeDog with Domestic
```